# Flat roof on garden office

Tags: roof, roofing

We have recently had a garden building built in our garden by a bespoke company.  However the roof has no gradient at all so we have standing water when it rains.  Is this ok?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info all we can say is "maybe"; could you add some details, and a picture? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Where is this property located? There are sometimes structures in certain localities built with a roof with no gradient. I have always assumed that the roof coverings were a special design and would not leak for an acceptable service life. Is the no gradient roof not uncommon where you are?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not OK. Standing water will deteriorate any membrane and eventually cause the roofing and roof structure to deteriorate.

The wetting and drying process puts stresses on the roofing. The edge of a “puddle” has different coefficients of expansion and contraction. This different movement will reduce the life of the roofing.

Good roof design is intended to shed water. (There was a short time in the 1980’s that designed a “pond” on the roof to create an insulated barrier to the elements, but we soon learned that any imperfection will allow the entire “pond” drain through any pinhole.)

Steep roofs seem to perform better and lasts longer than flatter roofs. (Have you ever noticed that old barn roofs don’t seem to leak, even though you can look up and see daylight coming through the roof?)